How to eliminate the duplicate row while keeping rows that do not have a duplicate?
I have a table in which there exists duplicate rows where the Product name is the same, but the value is different. I don't care which value I keep, I just want to get rid of the duplicate row and keep one. I am using SNO-SQL.
This is the table that I have:



Product
ID




Apple
N5


Apple
N5B


Banana
N4


Kiwi
N5


Kiwi
N5B


Lime
N4


Mango
N3


Pear
N5B



This is the table that I want:



Product
ID




Apple
N5


Banana
N4


Kiwi
N5B


Lime
N4


Mango
N3


Pear
N5B



It doesn't matter to me which of the different ID's is eliminated.
I'm really new to SQL so this is what I've tried:
SELECT DISTINCT
   PRODUCT,
   ID,
FROM PRODUCT_LOOKUP
WHERE PRODUCT IN ('APPLE', 'BANANA', 'KIWI', 'LIME', 'MANGO', 'PEAR')
AND ID IS NOT NULL //included because in the raw table, some IDs are null which I want to ignore.
ORDER BY PRODUCT ASC


this is a simple case of de-duplicate a table. can be done in many ways - pls google.

SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT_LOOKUP
WHERE PRODUCT IN ('APPLE', 'BANANA', 'KIWI', 'LIME', 'MANGO', 'PEAR')
AND ID IS NOT NULL
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT) = 1;

ROW_NUMBER just assigns a sequential number from 1 to n for every record with the same PRODUCT.  QUALIFY allows you to select the record where that value = 1.  You could also add a ORDER BY after the PARTITION BY PRODUCT area if you wanted to choose the lowest or largest ID valued record.

This SQL would do the trick for the example you posted:
select product, any_value(id) id
from product_lookup
group by 1;
